# Trigger rails controller function - Paypal Website Standard IPN

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paypal, controller

I've got a Paypal IPN that comes into a `PaymentNotificationsController` in my app. However, some variables depend on the number of items in a cart, so i want to extract them before creating the PaymentNotification.

So far, i've got:

```
class PaymentNotificationsController < ApplicationController
  protect_from_forgery except: [:create]
     def create
       PaymentNotification.create!(params: params, 
       item_number: params[:item_number], item_name: params[:item_name], quantity: params[:quantity] 
       render nothing: true
     end
end
```

However, when the notification comes from PayPal, it comes in the form of `item_name1, item_number1, quantity1, item_name2, item_number2, quantity2` and so on.
Even if its just one item, it would come as `item_name1, item_number1, quantity1, option1` and so on.

I have this function to try and extract the variables, but i don't know how to trigger the function. I tried using a `before_action` at the top of the controller but it didn't work. Returned `wrong number of arguments(0 for 1)`:

```
ITEM_PARAM_PREFIXES = ["item_name", "item_number", "quantity"]

def extract_ipn_items_params(params)
  item_params = []

  loop do
    item_num_to_test = item_params.length + 1
    item_num_suffix = item_num_to_test.to_s
    possible_param_name = ITEM_PARAM_PREFIXES[0] + item_num_suffix
    if params.include?(possible_param_name)
      this_item_params = {}
      ITEM_PARAM_PREFIXES.each do |prefix|
        this_item_params[prefix] = params[prefix + item_num_suffix]
      end
      item_params.push this_item_params
    else
      return item_params
    end
  end
end
```

So i'm asking, how do i trigger the function to extract the variables and put them into params[:item_number], params[:item_name], params[:quantity] for each item in the cart so if there are two items, two separate PaymentNotifications would be created?

**Note**: Both methods are in the same `PaymentNotificationsController`.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume your method `extract_ipn_items_params` already fetches the data you require, you can remove the params argument to the method, as the params is always available in the `actions/methods` of the controller.

```
ITEM_PARAM_PREFIXES = ["item_name", "item_number", "quantity"]

def extract_ipn_items_params
    mod_params = Hash.new{|k, v| k[v] = {} }

    ITEM_PARAM_PREFIXES.each do |item_data_key|
        key_tracker = 1
        loop do
            current_key = (item_data_key + key_tracker.to_s).to_sym
            if params.include? current_key
                mod_params[key_tracker][item_data_key] = params[current_key]
            else
                break
            end
            key_tracker += 1
        end
    end
    mod_params
end
```

The method returns a hash of hashes like:

`{1 => {item_name: 'Item 1', item_number: 1084, quantity: 15}}`, if you have nested attributes set up for a user, I think you should be able to do something like, not really sure, but should be possible:

`user.update(payment_notifications_attributes: extract_ipn_items_params)`

Let me know if that works for you.

**UPDATE**

Based on the Github Gist, here's something I was able to come up with:

```
class PaymentNotificationsController < ApplicationController
  protect_from_forgery except: [:create]

  ITEM_PARAM_PREFIXES = ["item_name", "item_number", "quantity", "option_name"]


   def create
    extract_ipn_items_params.each do |key, values|
      # this approach loops through all the returned results, nested attributes may help abstract this though
        PaymentNotification.create(values)  
        render nothing: true
    end

  def details
    # params.extract_ipn_items_params #this doesn't exist as params is an instance of ActionController::Parameters
    PaymentNotification.update_attributes(line_item_id: params[:item_number], product_title: params[:item_name], option_name: params[:option_name], quantity: params[:quantity])
  end

  private

    def additional_attributes
      # create this for additional merge attributes. A better place for these would be the parent of this
      {
        params: params, 
        cart_id: params[:invoice], 
        status: params[:payment_status], 
        transaction_id: params[:txn_id], 
        first_name: params[:first_name], 
        last_name: params[:last_name], 
        email: params[:payer_email], 
        address_name: params[:address_name], 
        address_street: params[:address_street], 
        address_city: params[:address_city], 
        address_state: params[:address_state], 
        address_zip: params[:address_zip], 
        address_country: params[:address_country]
      }
    end

    def extract_ipn_items_params
      mod_params = Hash.new{|k, v| k[v] = {}.merge(additional_attributes) }

      ITEM_PARAM_PREFIXES.each do |item_data_key|
          key_tracker = 1
          loop do
              current_key = (item_data_key + key_tracker.to_s).to_sym
              if params.include? current_key
                  mod_params[key_tracker][item_data_key] = params[current_key]
              else
                  break
              end
              key_tracker += 1
          end
      end
      mod_params
    end

end
```

Let me know if that fixes your problem.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So if i just add this before the `create` action, it would extract the items before running create? This is what the file looked like >> [https://www.dropbox.com/s/2f508296wb378wc/sublime.png?dl=0](https://www.dropbox.com/s/2f508296wb378wc/sublime.png?dl=0)

Comment: The data comes from paypal to the `PaymentNotificationsController`

Comment: No, running this before create wouldn't affect the params ATM, because you're not changing the state of the params, just extracting the attributes you require. In this case `item_name`, `item_number` and `quantity`. Now there are several ways of inserting those records to the db, nested params being on of them. Could you create a Github Gist showing your `PaymentNotificationsController`, so I could update my answer with another approach which uses a loop to insert the records

Comment: just tried this but didn't work >> [gist.github.com/d1t/7f3a9451500579da617134468beeca96](https://gist.github.com/d1t/7f3a9451500579da617134468beeca96) Attached the model aswell to give an idea of the whole picture

Comment: Thanks so much! It works, but i need the variables to be filled on create, cause i have after_create callbacks in the model. I tried using fetch to remove each individual variable from the Hash, but struggling. If you have time, please take a look >>[https://gist.github.com/d1t/7f3a9451500579da617134468beeca96](https://gist.github.com/d1t/7f3a9451500579da617134468beeca96)

Answer (score 0):

You should have payment_id so you can find it by using `gem 'paypal-sdk-rest'`

```
payment = PayPal::SDK::REST::Payment.find payment_id
```

then you could see all details in payment object

Comment: I can already see the details. When the notification comes, it creates just fine apart from the variables: item_name, item_number etc because PayPal sends them as item_name1, item_number1. I just need a rails way to extract them from the notification before creating!

Comment: I'm also using Paypal Website Standard and not the REST API